# Angular 6 package intra-module dependencies

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-packagr

I'm trying to create a library with multiple modules but having difficulties with module dependencies. I'm using Angular 6 with:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.7.0-rc.3",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0-rc.3",
"ng-packagr": "^4.0.0",
```

I started out by creating a new library using `ng g library package` which created the following structure

```
projects
|- package
   |- src
   |  |- lib
   |  |  |- *.ts
   |  |-public_api.ts
   |- ng-package.json
   |- package.json
   |- tsconfig.lib.json
```

I want to add a sub-package which will have a module with dependencies on the main package. The structure ng-packagr uses (as far as I could tell) for sub-packages is this:

```
projects
|- package
   |- src
   |  |- lib
   |  |  |- package.module.ts
   |  |-public_api.ts
   |- ng-package.json
   |- package.json
   |- tsconfig.lib.json
   |
   |- sub-package
   |   |-src
   |   |  |- sub-package.module.ts
   |   |- public_api.ts
   |   |- package.json
```

sub-package.module depends on package.module. I can't use relative paths for imports in sub-package.module since I get an error saying all code for the package should be in the rootDir.

When I try to use the path ng-packagr added to tsconfig (when creating the library) I get an error `Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null`.

I've tried adding `paths` and `lib\externals` properties to the ngPackage object in the sub-packages package.json but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you use any tool to generate sub-package? I am looking for a tool since I have a large library that need to be converted into this structure. :/

Comment: @Duke did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use relative paths of course. You should use absolute paths like `package-name/path/to/module`.

So you either create multiple packages (like `package-name/core`, `package-name/cli`, etc.) or you can use sub-entries. I recommend you read [this article](https://tomastrajan.medium.com/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3) to achieve that.